# SQL SERVER - Left Join does not work. Because?

Tags: sql-server

This works perfectly in MS Access.
Why not in MS SQL Server?

Can you help me solve it?

[Here's how my query is](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sByyBMzCDs4)

```
select * 
from tblPROestoque 
where idproduto = 8183
order by identrada desc

select top(1) * 
from tblPROestoque 
where idproduto = 8183
order by identrada desc

select *
from tblPROproduto pr
        left join (select top(1) idproduto, valcusto
                    from tblproestoque
                    order by identrada desc) tmp on tmp.idproduto = pr.idproduto
where pr.idproduto = 8183
```

Comment: That link is to Youtube. Where is your query? Post it as `Text`.

Comment: What do you mean with "doesn't work"?

Comment: I'm guessing your subquery doesn't return what you think it does, as it has no where clause but the top two queries you posted do. Try running the subquery on its own and seeing what it returns.

Comment: idproduct, valcusto
is returning nulls on left join

Comment: because Top 1 query should also have where clause.

Comment: @KumarHarsh with the syntax `LEFT JOIN ({subquery})` you can't reference the outer tables.

Comment: @Larnu , I am not saying that. I was just guessing something else.See Individual Top 1 query, it has where clause, so I thought that where clause Is missing in left join subquery.

Comment: @KumarHarsh ahh, you mean mean adding `where tmpalias.idproduto = 8183`. That would work.

Comment: @Larnu, Secondly,this Newbie already downvoted enough to get demotivated.One or Two downvoted is enough.

Comment: @KumarHarsh I suspect that was because initially thepost was just a link to YouTube. A lot of those voters would have come and gone now. I also didn't get a chance to revoke my vote before it was closed, so i have voted to reopen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the problem here is your understanding of how a subquery works. We have your query:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPROproduto pr
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP (1)
                       idproduto,
                       valcusto
                FROM tblproestoque
                ORDER BY identrada DESC) tmp ON tmp.idproduto = pr.idproduto
WHERE pr.idproduto = 8183;
```

We can separate this into 2 different parts:

```
SELECT TOP (1)
       idproduto,
       valcusto
FROM tblproestoque
ORDER BY identrada DESC;
```

and then:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPROproduto pr
     LEFT JOIN tmp ON tmp.idproduto = pr.idproduto
WHERE pr.idproduto = 8183;
```

This might explain to you why what you have isn't working. I'm guessing you are assuming that the `ON` clause on `tmp` is derived BEFORE the `SELECT` of the subquery. This isn't the case. The subquery will be derived, and then the `ON`. Thus the value of `tmp` will be whatever is rerturned in the query above.

I suspect what you want is:

```
SELECT *
FROM tblPROproduto pr
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP (1)
                       ca.idproduto,
                       ca.valcusto
                FROM tblproestoque ca
                WHERE ca.idproduto = pr.idproduto
                ORDER BY ca.identrada DESC) tmp
WHERE pr.idproduto = 8183;
```

*Edit: Added some sample data and explanations for the OP, to help their udnerstanding:*

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE Product (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                      Sku varchar(10),
                      ProductName varchar(25));
CREATE TABLE ProductOrder (ID int IDENTITY(1,1),
                           ProductID int,
                           OrderDate date,
                           NumberOrdered int);

INSERT INTO dbo.Product (Sku,
                         ProductName)
VALUES ('65432462','Lawn Mower'),
       ('98742347','Helicopter'),
       ('89465735','BBQ');
INSERT INTO dbo.ProductOrder (ProductID,
                              OrderDate,
                              NumberOrdered)
VALUES (1,'20180101',7),
       (1,'20180708',19),
       (2,'20180501',12),
       (3,'20180804',27);
GO

SELECT *
FROM dbo.Product;
SELECT *
FROM dbo.ProductOrder;
GO

--Use the example the OP has in their post:
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Product P
     LEFT JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 *
                FROM dbo.ProductOrder
                ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) PO ON PO.ProductID = P.ID
WHERE P.ID = 2;
--This returns NULLs for all the latter columns.
--Why?
--Inspect the subquery:
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM dbo.ProductOrder
ORDER BY OrderDate DESC;
--Product ID 3? 3 != 2 so the ON clause fails:
--Demonstrate
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Product P
     CROSS JOIN (SELECT TOP 1 * --CROSS JOIN joins all rows (creates a cartesian product)
                 FROM dbo.ProductOrder
                 ORDER BY OrderDate DESC) PO
WHERE P.ID = 2;
--The solution, use OUTER APPLY:
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Product P
     OUTER APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 *
                  FROM dbo.ProductOrder oa
                  WHERE oa.ProductID = P.ID --WHERE clause, this is like your ON
                  ORDER BY oa.OrderDate DESC) PO
WHERE P.ID = 2;
GO

DROP TABLE dbo.ProductOrder;
DROP TABLE dbo.Product;
```

Comment: There is a syntax error.

Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Comment: @RafaelBueno apologies, I'd missed the alias out. Give it a go now.

Comment: Guys, I can not understand why this simple query does not work perfectly like Access.
Is there anything wrong with the table fields?

Comment: @RafaelBueno The reason is because the subquery is always returning the `TOP 1` from `tblproestoque`, ordered by `identrada ` descending, regardless of what the value of `idproduto ` is. Most likely that row returned does not have a value of `8183` for `idproduto ` and so the `ON` clause is false, and doesn't return a value.

Comment: @RafaelBueno hopefully that sample data will help you understand how SQL Server works.

Answer (score 0):

@RafaelBueno, you basically need an `outer apply`. This is different in MSAcess.

See modified below:

Let me know if it works.

```
select *
from tblPROproduto pr
            outer apply (select top(1) idproduto, valcusto
                        from tblproestoque tmp
                        where tmp.idproduto = pr.idproduto
                        order by identrada desc) tmp 
where pr.idproduto = 8183
```

Comment: `ON` can't be used on an `APPLY`, and that won't stop the subquery being resolved before the `ON` (if it were valid)

Comment: Yes, you are right. edited now.

Comment: @Larnu, Yes, there was this mistake.

Comment: @MEdwin 

Your solution worked.

Many thanks, my friend.


Thank you to everyone who helped

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for the help and explanations. They helped a lot!

Comment: @RafaelBueno you're welcome, but you commented on the wrong answer ;)

Comment: @Larnu Yes, after posting it was that I realized. I'm in Brazil and now it's 6 o'clock in the morning and I'm over 20 hours without sleep.